# Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' and 'int'

Tags: asp.net

can someone help me to correct this code??
Sorry for my bad English, i'm Dutch.

My HTML:

```
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="XX-Large" 
    Text="Inloggen"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Voornaam"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Wachtwoord"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Login" />
```

My aspx.cs

```
    TextBox Textbox1 = new TextBox();

    if ((TextBox1 < 3) || (TextBox1 > 15))
       {

       }
    else
       {

       }
```

i hope someone can help me

Comment: And are you trying to compare length of text in textbox or numeric value entered into textbox - stating what do you want to achieve can be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing TextBox1 of Type `TextBox` with 3 that is `int`. TextBox and int could not be compared. In fact you want to compare value of TextBox with `int`.g  The text property gives you `string` which you should convert to int using `int.Parse` to compare it with `3`. and also the operands of `||` operator should be `boolean` and

```
if (int.Parse(TextBox1.Text) < 3) || int.Parse(TextBox1 > 15))
{

}
else
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
int a = int.Parse(Textbox1.Text);
if( a = < 3 || a > 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant compare with textbox itself comapre with its text value

```
if ((Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) < 3) || ((Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) > 15))
       {

       }
    else
       {

       }
```

Comment: Of course comparing a string with a number will raise another exception

Comment: @Steve yes i added a conversion

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to compare a Textbox with a number. Not the value of it. Solution:

```
int n1=ConvertToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
if(n<3 || n>15)
...
```

Don't forget to allow only numbers for input or it will throw an error. To avoid it:

```
try{
int n1=ConvertToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
    if(n<3 || n>15)
    ...
} catch {
//here you can do what you want to do if weird input is given
}
```

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format. can you also solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The property to use to extract the user input from a textbox is the `Text` property.

But the only correct way to handle the user input when a number is expected is through the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the datatype

```
TextBox Textbox1 = new TextBox();
.... 

int num;
if(Int32.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out num)
{
   // TryParse returns true, we have the number
   if(num < 3 || num > 15)
   {

   }
   else
   {

   }    
}
else
    // TryParse returns false, the input text is not a integer number
    ... message to your user... "we need a number, not something else"
```

[Int.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or Convert.ToInt32 ARE NOT TO BE USED here because they will raise an exception if your user types something like a word in your textbox instead of a valid number.

Of course I should not forget to mention that there are the [Validation controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx)